# Base de datos SQL con Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Estoy recien comenzando con este nuevo IDE (Visual Studio Community 2019) y necesito saber si se requiere instalar el `SQL Server Management Studio` para conectar y procesar datos `Sql` en este entorno. Por ahora he instalado, además del IDE, Almacenamiento y Procesamiento de datos (SQL), Desarrollo de escritorio `.NET`  y Desarrollo de la plataforma universal de windows.

De antemano, gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: EL SSMS solo te sirve para poder ver los datos de una manera mas visual si ya instalaste el gestor de base de datos como dices por lo tanto no es necesario. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Hola el visual estudio trae incorporado herramientas para trabajar con bases de datos Sql sin necesidad de instalar Sql o el SQL Server Management Studio . Yo te aconsejaría empezar a usar lo que ya viene incorporado en el IDE. Hay muchos tutoriales de como hacerlo y luego con algo mas de experiencia usar SQL Management. Te paso un link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KT7HpqtFksw

Comment: Buenas tardes Ludwig: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Para Visual Studio 2019 Community puedes adquirir el componente **Microsoft SQL Server 2016 LocalDB**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además de que puedes usar **paquetes Nuget** o **extensiones/conectores ADO.NET** para la incluir las librerías de la mayoría de las bases de datos distintas de SQL Server que puedes usar en Visual Studio.